# Get initial URL of iframe every time dialog opens

Tags: jquery

I have add an iframe into a dialog box. Every time I close the dialog box, holds the last URL of iframe and not the initial one! How can I make it open the initial URL every time I close and open it again?

**HTML EXAMPLE:**

```
<div id="opener_1">OPEN</div>

<div id="dialog_1">
<iframe src="http://www.wikipedia.com" width="570" height="320"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQUERY EXAMPLE:**

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $JQ_(function(){
    $JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog({autoOpen:false,
                                 width:'auto',
                                height:'auto',
                             resizable:false,
                                  show:{effect:"fade", duration:250},
                                  hide:{effect:"fade", duration:250}
    });
    $JQ_("#opener_1").click(function(){$JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog("open");});
    });
```

And a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GreenMadness/Y6hdj/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the iframe right after clicking the button, from the dialog `div`, and re-set its `src` attribute.

Check this updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6hdj/2/)

(By doing `frame.attr("src", src)`, you *restart* the iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your code:

```
var $frame = $("#myFrame");
var firstUrl = $frame.attr("src");

var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

$JQ_(function () {
    $JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 250
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 250
        },
        close: function () {
            $frame.attr("src", firstUrl);
        }
    });

    $JQ_("#opener_1").click(function () {
        $JQ_("#dialog_1").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Implements the `close` event of the dialog.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/Y6hdj/3/

**API Documentation**: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close

Comment: +1 nice approach, but I won't make `firstUrl` global and place it between `$JQ_(function () {` and the dialog call, visible to the close scope